# prove that complex limit $ \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty } e^{-z}$ doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried this but I'm not quit sure if it's true.

$ \lim_{z \rightarrow   \infty  } e^{-z}=  \lim_{z \rightarrow   0  } e^{\frac{-1}{z}}$

$\lim_{z \rightarrow   0  } e^{1/z}=\lim_{z \rightarrow   0  } e^{\frac{\overline {-z}}{|z|^{2}}}$

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow   (x,0) } e^{{\frac{-Re z+Imz}{(Rez)^{2}+(Im z)^{2}}}}=e^{\frac{1}{Im z}}$

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow   (0,y) } e^{{\frac{-Re z+Imz}{(Rez)^{2}+(Im z)^{2}}}}=e^{\frac{-1}{Re z}}$

if it's not true can you explain me why ?

Comment: Presumably, this is a complex limit $z\to \infty$,and   not the real limit $z\to\infty.$

Comment: Do you mean the norm of z goes to infinity,  or z goes to positive real infinity with 0 on the imaginary axis,  or...?

Answer (score 1):

For the limit to exist, it should be unique and exist via any path.

Assume limit exists, call it $L$.

Take $e^z=e^{x+iy}$.

$$L= \lim_{x\to\infty } e^{-x}=0.$$

$$|L|= \lim_{y\to\infty } |e^{-iy}|=1.$$

Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to prove a limit doesn’t exist, you need a proof by contradiction.

Assume there is a limit $L.$

Then, for  $\epsilon=1,$ there must be a real $N>0,$ such that if $|z|>N,$ then $\left|e^{-z}-L\right|<1.$

Let $m>N$ be an integer.

Then let $z_1=2\pi mi$ and $z_2=\pi(2m+1)i.$ Then each $|z_i|>N,$ and $e^{-z_1}=1, e^{-z_2}=-1.$

But:

$$\begin{align}2&=\left|e^{-z_1}-e^{-z_2}\right|\\
&\leq \left|e^{-z_1}-L\right|+\left|L-e^{z_2}\right|\\
&< 1+1=2
\end{align}$$

Contradiction.